# How to display custom error message for ActiveRecord::JDBCError in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a HTML table in my View to `create, update and delete` the records for a table called `Mast_Freq`.

The `Primary key` of this table is referenced by foreign key `'MastFreq'` in table `'AssFreq'` and some other tables. So, When I try to delete some record in the `MastFreq` I got the error message like the following.

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: [Sybase][JDBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Primary key for row in table 'MastFreq' is referenced by foreign key 'MastFreq' in table 'AssFreq': DELETE FROM "MastFreq" WHERE "MastFreq"."Frequency_Code" = 'A'
```

How can i display a custom error message to the user instead of this error message. This record should not be delete.

`Frequency_Code` is the primary key of the table `MastFreq`.

```
Controller:
----------
class Asset::MastFreqsController < AssetController

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::JDBCError, :with => :jdbc_error

  def destroy
    begin
      @asset_master_frequency = Asset::MastFreq.find(params[:id])
      result = @asset_master_frequency.destroy

      respond_to do |format|
    format.html{ redirect_to :action => :index}
    format.json{ render :json => result}
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::JDBCError
    end
  end

  protected
  def jdbc_error(exception)
    flash[:error] = "You Cannot delete this Frequency Code" + exception.inspect
    redirect_to asset_master_frequencies_path
  end
end
```

Comment: One way would be to place a rescue block around your call to delete, and to raise your desired custom message from within that.

Comment: yeah, But Please Give an example. I am new to ROR. Still learning. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rescue from errors in controllers or models by enclosing functionality in a begin/rescue/end block, as described by @user2463570.

But since you want to present a message to your user you can catch all errors of a specific type in a controller by adding the following line:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::JDBCError, :with => :jdbc_error

def jdbc_error(exception)
  flash[:error] = 'There was an error.......' + exception.inspect
  redirect_to root_url 
end
```

And show the error flash on the page

```
<%= flash[:error] %>
```

Some more information here: [ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html)

Included your code:

```
Controller:
----------
class Asset::MastFreqsController < AssetController

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::JDBCError, :with => :jdbc_error

  def destroy
    @asset_master_frequency = Asset::MastFreq.find(params[:id])
    result = @asset_master_frequency.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{ redirect_to :action => :index}
      format.json{ render :json => result}
    end        
  end

protected
  def jdbc_error
    flash[:error] = 'You Cannot delete this Frequency Code'
    redirect_to asset_master_frequencies_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. But still am confusing. I updated the question and provide an example of my controller. Please have a look and correct me.

Comment: Remove the begin/rescue/end blocks, just have the rescue_from line and the jdbc_error method, and you can remove the exception object from the jdbc_error message if you don't need it, it's an optional variable to let you access details of the error.

Comment: Into the view that `asset_master_frequencies_path` takes the user to. Updated my answer with your controller code.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

`begin

   ===

   your code

   ==

   rescue ActiveRecord::JDBCError

    puts "your custom error messages"

   end`

Comment: Do I need to do this condition in the Model or View?

Comment: In controller within begin you have to write all code its like a try catch in java Thanks

Comment: Hi Thanks, I added my controller for example. Please Have a look.